# htaccess File Basic Auth applying to other pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following in my root htaccess, running Apache 2.4.46

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all

Deny from 1.2.3.4  # block hackers
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id\=549($|&)
RewriteRule ^index3211\.html$ /donate/? [L,R=301]

<Files wp-login.php>
    AuthName Limited!
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "/home/example/www/www/wp-admin/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
</Files>
...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
```

But I am getting prompted for the password in some of the normal WP pages (on friendly URLs to index.php that have no reference to wp-login).

The page loads and the password prompt only appears at the end. I can't find any reference to wp-login.php in the Javascript source, HTML or Network tab requests (and there are no redirects).

Any tips on diagnosis?

Update: We have tracked it down to the WPBakery Media Grid element. I can't find the actual connection, so have no idea how/where it is triggering, but can turn the issue on and off with the element.

Comment: WP has it's own login page. Why do you want to use `Basic` auth for `wp-login.php`?

Comment: Thanks - because the site was successfully hacked due to a plugin security bug, we rebuilt it, but by then the URL was listed somewhere so we were getting thousands of attacks a day. This helps relieve the load on our budget server (we're a volunteer-run charity) and keeps things slightly more secure. (This is why I haben'

Comment: Sorry type - this is why I haven't posted the real URL - happy to send to you privately if possible. Huge thanks

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: 2.4.46, I just added it to the question too. Also added all remaining htaccess clauses, although don't think they'd affect it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this code in your .htacess:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#/login\.php[/?\s]#">
    AuthName Limited!
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "/home/example/www/www/wp-admin/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
</If>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure to test it from a new browser or after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Thanks very much, unfortunately the non-login pages still get the password prompt. (I sent you the page on LinkedIn - keeping it private for fear that I'm exposing some security flaw.)

Comment: Yes I totally understand. It is not good to expose your URL on a public forum.